# How many average draws to discover white balls?

Tags: probability

There are $N$ balls in a bag.

If only 1 ball is white (the rest are all black), the average number of extractions (without replacement) to discover the white ball is $N\over2$.

If two balls are white, the average number of extractions to discover both white balls is ${2\over3} N$. Is this correct?

Can this formula be generalized for $W$ white balls as : ${W\over W+1} N$ ?

Comment: Where does that $N/2$ for 1 white ball (and $N-1$ black) come from? It seems wrong either with or without replacement (putting the drawn ball back every time).

Comment: I see. So if N/2 is wrong, how many extractions will one do on average to discover the single white ball? (considering the "without replacement" scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E(n, w)$ be the average number of draws needed to discover all white balls within a bag with $n$ balls (in which there are $w$ white balls). I assume that balls are drawn without replacement.

The answer is $E(n, w) = \frac{w}{w + 1} (n + 1)$. So there is a mistake in a question, as $E(n, 1)$ is $\frac{n + 1}{2}$.

To see why $E(n, 1) = \frac{n + 1}{2}$ we proceed by induction on $n$. The base $n = 1$ is obvious. On the other hand,
$$E(n + 1, 1) = \frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{n}{n + 1} (1 + E(n, 1)).$$
Indeed, with probability $\frac{1}{n + 1}$ we take a white ball and we are done. With probability $\frac{n}{n + 1}$ we are left with a bag $n$ balls, with one white ball within (one draw is already done). Replacing $E(n, 1)$ with $\frac{n + 1}{2}$, we obtain:
$$E(n + 1, 1) = 1 + \frac{n}{n + 1} \cdot \frac{n+ 1}{2} = \frac{n + 2}{2}.$$

General case is rather similar. The proof is again by induction on $n$. More precisely, we prove by induction on $n$ that the for all $n$ and for all $1\le w\le n$ the following holds
$$E(n, w) = \frac{w}{w + 1}(n + 1).$$

The base $n = 1$ is again obvious. So assume that $1 \le w \le n + 1$. If $w = n + 1$, then clearly, $E(n + 1, w) = n + 1 = \frac{w}{w + 1}(n + 2)$, as required. Tha case $w = 1$ is already done. So, assuming that $2\le w\le n$, we obtain:

$$E(n + 1, w) = \frac{w}{n + 1} (1 + E(n, w - 1)) + \frac{n  + 1 - w}{n + 1} (1 + E(n, w)).$$
Indeed, with probability $\frac{w}{n}$ we are left with $n$ balls, among which there are $w - 1$ white balls, and with probability $\frac{n + 1 - w}{n + 1}$ we are left with  $n$ balls, among which there are $w$ white balls. Substituting $E(n, w - 1) = \frac{w - 1}{w} (n + 1), E(n, w) = \frac{w}{w + 1} (n + 1)$, we obtain
$$E(n + 1, w) = 1 + \frac{w}{n + 1}\cdot \frac{w - 1}{w} (n + 1) + \frac{n + 1 - w}{n + 1} \cdot \frac{w}{w + 1} (n + 1) = \frac{w}{w + 1}(n + 2),$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple argument based on symmetry:

Imagine you add a **red** ball. Now there are $N+1$ balls, and you deal them out into a circle. The $W+1$ red & white balls chop the circle up into $W+1$ intervals. By symmetry each interval is equi-distributed. Since they add up to $N+1$, by linearity of expectation each interval is of expected length ${N+1 \over W+1}$. Now rearrange the circle into a line: Starting with the red ball and going clockwise.  You now have a linear sequence of $N$ black & white balls, and the balls up to the last white = the balls in the $W$ intervals clockwise from the red ball.  So the expected value is $W{N+1 \over W+1}$.

Hopefully this explains *why* the formula works.  :)